# Nested form tag behavior

Tags: html, forms

I know you 'should not' do this but I noticed something interesting with forms nested within a parent form element.  If you have mulitple forms the rendering engine seems to strip out the first child form then remove all other child forms and add them after the closing form tag of the parent. Why does the rendering engine behave this way? Tested in Chrome and Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>Form Test 1</h2>
        <form id="form1">
            <form id="form2">
            </form>
            <form id="form3">
            </form>
            <form id="form4">
            </form>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you open this in a browser form 2 will be removed and all others added after form 1.

Comment: "it’s not a bug, it’s a feature", Chrome fixe HTML to ensure a correct display if your HTML is not valid. 
Why you need nested form ? Create one form with all your field ?

Comment: My question is in the question, why does the rendering engine behave this way? I will update that part in my original question. Also @ben there is a crm returning forms to another form element and I was trying to figure out why only the first form returned was being stripped out. "I" do not require nested forms, on the contrary, I would like all the rest to be stripped out by default as well.

Comment: Nested forms are [invalid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/542251). All bets are off. If you produce invalid HTML the browser is free to interpret how it sees fit, there is no w3 standards to abide to. The fix for this is to not produce invalid HTML. Why it did this, why not? It made the best attempt it could to parse invalid syntax.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for that.